# How to do that authorization or encrypted URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make encrypted and authorization url in client side in my below code when i click on button then url is open this is fine but i want to make url is open in encrypted format in client side

like that url is open [https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/%7Eece533/images/airplane.png) but i want to make this type url something [https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/xxx%$#@yuy](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/%7Eece533/images/xxx%$#@yuy) airplane.png is open in encypted format so that the reason is if anyone copy the url and not able to open in different network or different browser.

so how can we do that.anybody suggest and help me out.

my full react code https://codepen.io/svpan/pen/NWdJvmX

```
 const response = await fetch(url1);
      
      const res = await response.json();
      // alert(res.url)
      console.log(res)
      console.log("row id " + rowID)
      
       let object_ = {};
      
      res.map(item=>{
        // console.log(item.url)
        if(item.id === rowID){
          object_ = item;
        }
      })
```

Comment: anyone suggest and help me out this???

Comment: Couldn't you authenticate your request in the header? I guess you could have your web server switch out the encrypted url somehow, but I do not see how that would be more secure than an encrypted session cookie.

Comment: @thomi thanks for reply any suggestion and idea on that how can we do that i want to url secure in client side

Comment: @thomi is it possible to do that authentication or encrypted url in client side using reactjs ???

Comment: @thomi https://codepen.io/svpan/pen/NWdJvmX in this code is it poosible to make secure url